# imacros: extract image url

Tags: image, extract, imacros

I want to extract only image url by id in this code:

```
<img id="imgFull" src="http://mysite/images/51cBAfufUrL.jpg" class="image-stretch-vertical frontImage" style="max-width:230px; max-height:346px;">
```

And this is my imacros

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:imgFull EXTRACT=TXT
```

It returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:imgFull EXTRACT=HTM
```

From there you can extract the source of image with regular expression.

src="http://mysite/images/51cBAfufUrL.jpg"

```
text=text.match(/src.*\"/);
```

You can check this regular expression here. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

You have to use JavaScript scripting for this or EVAL

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imacros+javascript

http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

Or you can visit my profile and in question/answers section find examples of JS scripting.

Answer (score 0):

iMacros Doesn't support to extract src directly from HTML element. For this, you have to extract html element and after that using javascript eval with regex you can easily get src or any other part of html element

You can simply get SRC with the following code with iMacros

```
TAG XPATH="//img[@id="imgFull"]" EXTRACT=HTM
SET SRC EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/src.*class/)[0].replace(/src=\"/,\"\").replace(/\"\\sclass/,\"\");")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{SRC}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=SRC.csv
```